# Error while install postgresql 15

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, postgresql

i have problem while installing postgresql on my ubuntu 22.04.03 , i was follow step-by-setp guide on postgresql page, and youtube but still have this problem

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-15 : Depends: postgresql-common (>= 241~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libllvm14 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: sysstat but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Postgresql-15 is not in the standard repos for Ubuntu 22.04, but is in Ubuntu 23.04.  If you really need the 15 version, consider the later version of the OS (non LTS though).